# Pad string to same visual length

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I need to pad a string to the same visual length as other strings:

when I use the `.PadRight()` function the strings do have the same length, but visually they are very different:

```
some text                                                        140
some longer text blah blah                                       1234
even longer text super long blah blah                            4444
```

*Here on SO it appears correctly, because the strings have the same length*

Reality TextBox:
[image]

Reality RDLC:
[image]

How can I right align the numbers with some space between the text?

Desired behavior:
[image]

(Text aligned on left line, numbers aligned on right line.)

How I construct the strings:

```cs
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("some text".PadRight(65));
        sb.AppendLine("140");

        sb.Append("some longer text blah blah".PadRight(65));
        sb.AppendLine("1234");

        sb.Append("even longer text super long blah blah".PadRight(65));
        sb.AppendLine("4444");

        MyTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: If you want something like your third screenshot, you should probably create separate controls for each of those text.

Comment: If you want to align stuff by padding, you need to use a fixed-width font.

Comment: Are these strings purely for display, i.e. the user isn't typing into the TextBox? If so, you might be better off using a [`RichTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to display them - then you can add formatting information.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes the text is purely for display. How would one format the text so it is aligned in the RichTextBox?

Comment: Why are you not using Table in RDLC? or DataGridView in WinForms?

Comment: Yes, to be honest it's rather fiddly to justify text programmatically in a RichTextBox. `DataGridView` or just using separate `Label` controls for the left and right strings would be much easier.